# how to implement a search location box in google map in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

this code save the longitude and latitude of a current location ..i need to know how i will apply the search button for finding different location to save their longitude and latitude

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var long = 0;
         var lat = 0;
         if (navigator.geolocation) {
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
                 var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
                 var mapOptions = {
                     center: LatLng,
                     zoom: 13,
                     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 };
                 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: LatLng,
                     map: map,
                     title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
                 });
                 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                     infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
                     infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                     long = e.latLng.lng();
                     lat = e.latLng.lat();
                     document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
                     document.getElementById("lng").value = long;
                 });
             });
             google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
                 var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtPlaces'));
                 google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
                     var place = places.getPlace();
                     var address = place.formatted_address;
                     var latitude = place.geometry.location.k;
                     var longitude = place.geometry.location.D;
                     var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                     mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                     mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
                     alert(mesg);
                 });
             });

         } else {
             alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
         }
</script>




    <form id="form1" runat="server">


<div id="dvMap" style="width: 800px; height: 600px">
   </div>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="lat" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
   <asp:HiddenField ID="lng" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />

   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />


        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <span>Location:</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtPlaces" style="width: 250px" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

server side code ::

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         Double latitude = Convert.ToDouble(lat.Value);
        Double longitude = Convert.ToDouble(lng.Value);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);


        string query1 = "insert into tbl(longi,lati) values (@lati, @longi)";

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lati", latitude);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longi", longitude);

                con.Open();

                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


                con.Close();    
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example demonstrates how to search a place and save its location:

```js
function initialize() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


    
    var input = document.getElementById('searchbox');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);


    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        //get first place
        var place = places[0];

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        //var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        //bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        //map.fitBounds(bounds);

        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);


        //save location goes here...
        var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        document.getElementById('latbox').value = (lat);
        document.getElementById('lngbox').value = (lng);


    });
}
initialize();
```

```html
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
   
<input type="text" value="Lat:" id="latbox">
<input type="text" value="Lng:" id="lngbox">
<br/>
<input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 480px; height: 320px;"></div>
```